# Android Room foreign key

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

> **error**: Product has a foreign key (categoryId) that references Category
>   (id) but Category does not have a unique index on those columns nor
>   the columns are its primary key. SQLite requires having a unique
>   constraint on referenced parent columns so you must add a unique index
>   to Category that has (id) column(s).

**Category**

```
@Entity(
  tableName = "categories",
  indices = [Index("id"), Index("languageId")],
  primaryKeys = ["id", "languageId"],
  foreignKeys = [(ForeignKey(
    entity = Language::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"],
    childColumns = ["languageId"]
  ))]
)
@TypeConverters(ChildCategoryTypeConverter::class)
data class Category(
  val id: String,
  val name: String,
  val image: String?,
  val children: List<Category>?
) {

  @field:Transient var selected = false
  lateinit var languageId: String
}
```

**Product**

```
@Entity(
  tableName = "products",
  indices = [Index("id"), Index("languageId"), Index("categoryId")],
  primaryKeys = ["id", "languageId", "categoryId"],
  foreignKeys = [
    (ForeignKey(
      entity = Language::class,
      parentColumns = ["id"],
      childColumns = ["languageId"]
    )),
    (ForeignKey(
      entity = Category::class,
      parentColumns = ["id"],
      childColumns = ["categoryId"]
    ))
  ]
)
data class Product(
  val id: String,
  val title: String?,
  val description: String?,
  @field:SerializedName("calory") val calorie: String?,
  val delivery: String?,
  val price: String?,
  @field:SerializedName("main_image") val mainImage: String?,
  @field:SerializedName("detail_image") val detailImage: String?
) {

  lateinit var languageId: String
  lateinit var categoryId: String
}
```

I know making `indices = [Index("id", unique = true), Index("languageId")]` in Category class solves the problem but i don't get what's the issue here. Referenced foreign key is already defined as primary key in Category class.

Could you please guide me here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definitions are filled with redundancies. It's not advisable to have have a foreignKey as also the primary key. User `@PrimaryKey` only for `id` even though `languageId` might be unique, it's a referential constraint for another table

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. I was only following [samples for android architecture components](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/vo/Contributor.kt)